# Find the First Order ODE given the Second Order ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the second order ODE $$y''=\frac{(y')^{2}}{y}+y^{3}+y^{2}+y,\qquad y=y(x)\qquad\qquad (1),$$ I want to find the corresponding first order ODE. I tried by multiplying throughout by $y'$ to get $$y'y''=\frac{(y')^{3}}{y}+y'y^{3}+y'y^{2}+y,$$ which upon integration gives $$\frac{1}{2}(y')^{2}=\int\frac{(y')^{3}}{y}dx+\frac{1}{4}y^{4}+\frac{1}{3}y^{3}+\frac{1}{2}y^{2}\qquad\qquad (2).$$ So, I do not know how to compute $\int\frac{(y')^{3}}{y}dx$ (which might mean that this approach might not be suitable for this case)

Any suggestions to overcome this or *any other methods* would be appreciated.

---

Edit:

Please note that the corresponding first order ODE is $$(y')^{2}=\frac{2}{3}y^{4}+y^{3}+2y^{2}+cy,$$ where $c$ is the constant of integration. I found this by taking the general form $a_{1}y^{4}+a_{2}y^{3}+a_{3}y^{2}+a_{4}y$ (I chose this because of equation $(2)$) and substituting this into equation $(1)$ to solve for the $a_{i}$'s.

---

Comment: This antiderivative cannot be expressed in terms of standard functions.

Comment: if it was like $2y''=\frac{(y')^{2}}{y}+y^{3}+y^{2}+y$ then we can solve for it like this. first bring fractional term to left hand side:
$$\frac{2yy''-(y')^2}{y}=y^3+y^2+y$$ then multiply both sides by $y'$ and divide it by $y$. then we get:
$$\frac{2yy'y''-(y')^3}{y^2}=y^2y'+yy'+y'$$
now integrate both sides to get:
$$ \frac{(y')^2}{y}=\frac{y^3}{3}+\frac{y^2}{2}+y+C$$

Comment: Dear @ K.K.McDonald, Would you mind adding this as an answer?This is exactly the kind of manipulation I was looking for and works well for other ODEs by taking the form $(y')^{n}/y^{m}$.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a differential equation that doesn't explicitly include the independent variable, you can reduce the degree by letting $v=y^{\prime}=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Then
$$y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{dy^{\prime}}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=v\frac{dv}{dy}$$
So our equation is transformed to
$$v\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{v^2}y+y^3+y^2+y$$
Rearrange to
$$\frac{dv}{dy}-\frac1yv=\left(y^3+y^2+y\right)v^{-1}$$
This is Bernoulli's differential equation and we solve by letting $v=u^n$. Then
$$nu^{n-1}\frac{du}{dy}-\frac1yu^n=\left(y^3+y^2+y\right)u^{-n}$$
We can eliminate the dependence on $u$ on the right if $n-1=-n$ so $n=\frac12$ and $v=u^{\frac12}$. Then
$$\frac{du}{dy}-\frac2yu=2\left(y^3+y^2+y\right)$$
Now that the equation has been reduced to first order linear, we can determine the integrating factor
$$\mu=e^{\int-\frac2ydy}=e^{-2\ln y}=\frac1{y^2}$$
Then
$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{u}{y^2}\right)=\frac1{y^2}\frac{du}{dy}-\frac2{y^3}u=\frac1{y^2}\left(\frac{du}{dy}-\frac2yu\right)=\frac2{y^2}\left(y^3+y^2+y\right)=2y+2+\frac2y$$
So
$$\frac{u}{y^2}=\frac{v^2}{y^2}=\frac{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2}{y^2}=y^2+2y+2\ln|y|+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$y''=\frac{(y')^{2}}{y}+y^{3}+y^{2}+y$ is an ODE of autonomous kind. It can be transformed to a linear ODE thanks to the next changes of variables. The final resul can be expressed on implicit form with an integral. There is no closed form.

[image]